Preventing content blur in scaled iframe with CSS border-radius
I have an iframe inside a container that dynamically scales the iframe based on available space in the div.
if there is no border-radius, the content of the iframe is rendered with no problem. But as soon as I add border-radius to the iframe or its container, the content becomes blurry. How can I prevent this?

Although i haven't experienced this issue i remember seeing something similar a while back where it was mentioned it could be due to the indexing. The resolution was position the container div relative and iframe absolute and change the z-index of iframe to be lower than container div. Can you give that a try and see if it helps.
IF it doesn't work, could you create a sandbox/snippet with reproducible code for others to debug?
